# JavaScript upTime function - Not recognizing ID of variable

Tags: javascript

My goal is for calcyear (cyear) to initially start at the value "8". Every time the day count reaches 364, I want a value of "1" to be subtracted from this 8 value, until it reaches zero.

For some reason, the p id does not seem to be recognizing the calcyear id... Or perhaps it is, but the code is in error?

Entire code:

```
<html>
<style>
#countup p {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
}
#paragraph2 p {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="countup">
  We are in day
  <p id="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">of the calendar. This day has been going on for </p>
  <p id="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hours, </p>
  <p id="minutes">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">minutes, and </p>
  <p id="seconds">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds"> seconds.</p>
</div>

<div id="paragraph2">
<p>We are in month</p>
<p id="months">00</p>
<p>of the year.</p>
</div>

<div id="paragraph2">
<p>In </p>
<p id="calcyear">0</p>
<p> years an intercalation week will be added.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onload=function() {
  upTime('mar,20,2016,00:00:00'); 
}
function upTime(countTo) {
  now = new Date();
  countTo = new Date(countTo);
  difference = (now-countTo);

  days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
  hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
  mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
  secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
  mons=Math.floor(difference/(24*60*60*1000*24)*1);

  cyear= 8
  years=Math.floor(days / 364)
  if (years > 1){ cyear = cyear - 1}

  document.getElementById('days').firstChild.nodeValue = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
  document.getElementById('minutes').firstChild.nodeValue = mins;
  document.getElementById('seconds').firstChild.nodeValue = secs;
  document.getElementById('months').firstChild.nodeValue = mons;
  document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years;
  document.getElementById('calcyear').firstChild.nodeValue = cyear;


  clearTimeout(upTime.to);
  upTime.to=setTimeout(function(){ upTime(countTo); },1000);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like your code is incomplete. elements days, hours, etc., are not defined, can you provide entire code

Comment: What do you mean by "p id". What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Refering to: <p id="calcyear">0</p>

Comment: @PhillipLebsack It seems its because you don't have an element with the id `"years"`. The error causes the code to stop there, and not update `calcyear` which would happen afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There's no element with the id `years`, so your code stops there.

Just add `<p id="years">0</p>` to your code and it should run.

Comment: Just highlighting the issue can not be an answer.. Do provide solution as well....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this section of code:

```
document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years;
```

In your HTML there isn't an element with the id `'years'`, as such you will receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Since there is no such element with the id `'years'`, then `document.getElementById('years')` would return `null`. This error also stops execution, so the next lines would not run. So because it's after that `calcyear` isn't updated.

```
document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years; // Stops
document.getElementById('calcyear').firstChild.nodeValue = cyear; // Not ran
```

It seems like you intended to add it but may of forgotten:

```
<div id="paragraph2">
<p>We are in month</p>
<p id="months">00</p>
<p>of the year </p>
<p id="years">00</p>  <!-- Added line -->
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/swf30hdt/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add the element within the code, so it holds the information behind the scenes?

Comment: @PhillipLebsack Do you mean adding that element dynamically with JavaScript? Could you clarify what you mean by *"holds the information behind the scenes"*, do you want the element hidden?

Comment: Essentially. Like a variable, holding the information within the function, so the "cyear" can work properly, but without the "years" being displayed in the div.

Comment: It's already held in your global variable `years`, if you don't need it you can simply remove the line: `document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years;`. And the code will work fine.

Comment: Outstandingly brilliant. Didn't think about that. Thanks a lot!